# Weird compiling behavior using enumeration as arguments

Tags: c, function, parameters, enums, pic

I'm trying to compile this (portion) of code in MPLAB-X, with XC8 compiler, v1.20:

```
typedef enum i2cMode {MASTER = 0,SLAVE=1,OFF=2} i2c_mode;
void i2c_init(i2c_mode mode, uint8_t bus);
```

and it is inside to an header file. I tried every combination, also without the number association, but at the end it will output always this:

```html
(908) exit status = 1
make[2]: *** [build/pierin/production/main.p1] Error 1
../emu.X/i2c.h:48: error: label identifier expected
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
../emu.X/i2c.h:48: error: "}" expected
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
../emu.X/i2c.h:48: error: no identifier in declaration
../emu.X/i2c.h:48: error: ";" expected
../emu.X/i2c.h:48: warning: missing basic type; int assumed
../emu.X/i2c.h:51: error: "," expected
../emu.X/i2c.h:51: error: can't mix prototyped and non-prototyped arguments
../emu.X/i2c.h:51: error: function body expected
main.c:41: error: undefined identifier "SLAVE"
main.c:41: error: too many function arguments
```

where at 48 there is the enum typdef and 51 is the function prototype. In main I can see that this do not create the SLAVE enumeration, neither the protoyping. 
Do I need to use normal variables? It should work, but this is not the case. I would like to use the i2c_mode type and use the enum. Is it wrong or unnecessary here?

Comment: Please verify, that this specific compiler understands the syntax. I compiled your code with gcc 4.6.2 and it just works fine.

Comment: It should work, but give it another try without the label `i2cMode` after the enum keyword: `typedef enum { MASTER=0, SLAVE=1, OFF=2 } i2c_mode;`

Comment: I've already did. All combinations. Also without assign a number to the enum variables. The rest of code is right because without the enum compiles.

Answer (score 0):

I solved. It was a problem of automatic reading of the Link Peripheral Libraries that was reading the default i2c.h header, creating conflicts. Changing enum names had solved. Thanks.